# Background Image is repeating

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm having problems in setting background image in my asp.net web application.

Problem is: when I set no-repeat, the image is set according to its resolution 640*480 and the remaining page is left blank.

If I don't set any repeat in css file, then image is converted into one and half images.

I want my image is stretched along the screen.

mycss file

```
body
{
 font-size: .80em;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
color: #696969;
} /*default setting */

<body style="background-image: url(' <%= imgPath %>')" >
</body>
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!!

Comment: There are some examples in this [CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use background-size

[background-size | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

like

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

or

```
/* include vendor prefixes */
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: it worked, but I'm losing pixels. Now I'm using image of 1024x780. Is there any way to do it right ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-size:cover` and `no-repeat`

```
body{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/pL00uu2s/1/)

Comment: It worked, but not completely. The upper part of image is cut and remaining will be displayed perfectly

Comment: not possible. it should work. any online link available?